# chart.js , cant make the graph using AJAX

Tags: ajax, charts

I have started using chart.js, and I am trying to use it with Ajax. I am running in chrome and used the debugger but it is not giving me any kind of error. The problem is, I cant see the pie graph i am trying to build.

The code is all in one place as it is a test code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Pie Chart with Custom Tooltips</title>
<script src="Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<style>
#canvas-holder 
{
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
#chartjs-tooltip
{
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-transition: all .1s ease;
  transition: all .1s ease;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

.chartjs-tooltip-key
{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="canvas-holder" style="width: 300px;">
    <canvas id="chart-area2" width="300" height="300" />
</div>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

$.ajax({
    url: "registo.php",
    method: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);

        var dados=[];
        var score = [];

        for(var i in data) {

            score.push(data[i].nome_operadora);
            dados.push(data[i].conta);
        }



  var config = {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            data: dados,
            backgroundColor: [
                "#F7464A",
                "#46BFBD",
                "#FDB45C",
                "#949FB1",
                "#4D5360",
            ],
        }],
        labels:score
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        tooltips: {
            enabled: true,
        }
    }
};





var ctx2 = document.getElementById("chart-area2").getContext("2d");
new Chart(ctx2, config);





    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});





 });




</script>
```

The  registo.php is as follows :

```
<?php
include "../Connections/conexao.php";
$query1 =  "SELECT `op`.`nome`, COUNT(*) AS conta FROM `op` INNER JOIN `sim` ON `op`.`idcod`=`sim`.`cod_operadora` GROUP BY `op`.`idcod`
";

$result1 = mysqli_query($conexao,$query1);

$data = array();
foreach ($result1 as $row1) {
$data[] = $row1;
}

print json_encode($data);

?>
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT : i have solved my issue, it wasnt related to AJAX  nor chart.js, but with the JSON object, I forgot to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to parse the JSON object. It is solved now

```
success: function(data) {
        obj = JSON.parse(data);
alert(obj);
        var dados=[];
        var score = [];

        for(var i in obj) {

            score.push(obj[i].nome_operadora);
            dados.push(obj[i].conta);
        }
 alert(score);
```